# Move to next Row in dataGridView

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, oledb

I am trying to develop a form which will search the database for the entered name. save the selected row and then move to the next one. but when i search again it clears the previously saved row.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView DV = new DataView(datatable);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("proName LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM productDetails",connection);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Zimad\Desktop\project1.accdb";           
        connection.Open();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        dataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
        connection.Close();
        nRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nRow < dataGridView1.RowCount)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[nRow].Selected = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows[++nRow].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

button1 is used to save the selected row.

Comment: You are resetting the datasource with `dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;`, so you lose any previous selection when you do that.  You would have to store the selection information and put it back in after that call.

Comment: @LarsTech exactly the part which i cant figure out. how am i gonna store it and how am i gonna recall it?

Comment: Probably with some kind of key for each selected row, and then when the DataSource is updated, loop through the rows to find the matching keys.

Comment: Why you cannot search straight from database. Without loading all rows at the loading of form. Then you can show in the datagridview only rows founded by search text

Answer (score 0):

@Fabio is right. What i did here is that i loaded the search results in a textbox and later loaded the information against the item in the dataGridView

```
     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Visible = true;

        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select * FROM ProductDetails";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["proName"].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader["proName"].ToString());
            }

        }
        connection.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select * FROM ProductDetails";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["proName"].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = reader["proName"].ToString();
            }

        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```